# POSIX threads - attempting lock on empty spinlock

Tags: c, pthreads, spinlock

What happens if I try to lock on an invalid pthread type spinlock? The scenario might occur on a linked list using optimistic synchronization, utilizing a spinlock on each node, between the phase of finding the desired nodes and actually locking them. When I find them, I have a valid reference towards them, but what happens if they are e.g. deleted before I am able to lock them? The result would be trying to lock on a NULL pointer - can that cause the program to terminate, or will it just make `pthread_spin_lock()` return with a specific value?

Comment: If by deleted, you mean no longer an object, then you can be sure it is undefined behavior.

Comment: That's a good issue to what I am trying to do - for a university exercise, I am requested to implement "optimistic synchronization" - that is, removing and adding nodes searches the list without locks, locks the nodes AFTER they are found, and then ensures the locked nodes are still valid inside the list before proceeding. But the latter validation does not address the main issues it seems - that is, things might occur between finding and locking the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) is clear: *The results are undefined if any of these functions is called with an uninitialized spin lock.*

After an object is deleted, it should be regarded as if it is in an uninitialized state. (Also depends on what the definition of deleted is in this case, which we didn't clarify, so there might be additional caveats.)

It is not specified what happens if you pass a NULL to the function. It will probably return EINVAL: *If an implementation detects that the value specified by the lock argument to pthread_spin_lock() or pthread_spin_trylock() does not refer to an initialized spin lock object, it is recommended that the function should fail and report an [EINVAL] error.*